# list of strings to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner. I want to convert a list with strings into a numpy matrix, For instance,
`['hello','world','this']` to `[[h,e,l,l,o],[w,o,r,l,d],[t,h,i,s]]`. I am looking for a generalized solution for a n by n numpy matrix.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, what code have you written so far? please refrain from trying to get help without any effort yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, like that:

```py
words = ['hello','world','this'] 
letters = [ list(x) for x in words ]
```

And then create a numpy array:

```py
arr = np.array(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

plz like this answer

```
arr = ['hello', 'world', 'this']
arr = [list(i) for i in arr]

print(arr)
```

output: [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], ['t', 'h', 'i', 's']]

Comment: That isn't a numpy array output though

Answer (score 0):

You can't get square arrays if you don't have same length of the array and same number of chars in each string. However you can get m by n numpy array by filling up smaller strings with a special token.

```
import numpy as np


a_main = ['hello', 'world', 'this']

a = [list(a_i) for a_i in a_main]
print(a)
cols = 5
oov_token = 'Z'

for i in range(len(a)):
  if len(a[i]) < cols:
    a[i] = list( ''.join(k for k in a[i]).rjust(cols, oov_token))

print(a)

a = np.array(a, dtype = np.chararray)
print(a.shape)
print(a)
```

```
[['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], ['t', 'h', 'i', 's']]
[['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], ['Z', 't', 'h', 'i', 's']]
(3, 5)
[['h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o']
 ['w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd']
 ['Z' 't' 'h' 'i' 's']]
```